# Server connection to client behind NAT

Tags: c#, .net, networking, network-programming

I've made a server/client application in C#.

My question is the following: Let's say a client is behind an NAT (Like a router) and tries to connect to a server. From the server's perspective, the server only knows the client's external IP address. How do you determine exactly which computer to send the packets to that is behind an NAT? I understand port forwarding from the router on the client's end is a common way of solving these type of problems but if you look at applications like Skype, port forwarding is not necessary to properly establish a connection between the server and however many clients behind the NAT. This question can be asked vice-versa as well (I.E: client to server behind NAT).

I'm pretty new at socket programming so I'd love to hear any guidelines or materials that I can read over to fully understand this stuff.

Comment: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk361/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094831.shtml

Comment: Check out SignalR.  It makes this easy.

Comment: Regarding how peer-to-peer applications (Skype & Friends) might be setting up their connections through `NAT`ting routers and even firewalls google for `UDP Hole Punching` and/or `STUN`.

Comment: Off topic? Are you out of your minds? Have any of you that closed it ever read the scope of this forum? It looks like some people have no better work to do than vote to close questions that do not understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't worry about NAT in the application layer. If you receive a message with an IP say 200.51.255.79 you can send the answer to the same IP. Routers will handle the NAT and further routing automatically. It's not like this with port forwarding of course but it is with NAT.

Skype works in a very interesting way to get around port forwarding and firewalls using a server sided database of current ips and ports where each user is waiting for a response. You should look that up on the internet for a full explanation. It's a really good read =).

Comment: A link to get someone started would be great!